# Is there a way to capture URL parameters with django in urls.py?

Tags: python, django

I am trying to write something elegant where I am not relying on Request object in my code.  All the examples are using: 
    (r'^hello/(?P.*)$', 'foobar.views.hello')
but it doesn't seem like you can post to a URL like that very easily with a form.  Is there a way to make that URL respond to ..../hello?name=smith

Answer (score 3):

Absolutely. If your url is mapped to a function, in this case `foobar.views.hello`, then that function might look like this for a GET request:

```
def hello(request):
    if request.method == "GET":
        name_detail = request.GET.get("name", None)

        if name_detail:
            # got details
        else:
            # error handling if required.
```

Data in encoded forms, i.e. POST parameters, is available if you HTTP POST from `request.POST`.

You can also construct these yourself if you want, say, query parameters on a POST request. Just do this:

```
PARAMS = dict()
raw_qs = request.META.get('QUERY_STRING', '') # this will be the raw query string
if raw_qs:
    for line in raw_qs.split("&"):
        key,arg = line.split("=")
        PARAMS[key] = arg
```

And likewise for form-encoded parameters in non POST requests, do this:

```
FORM_PARAMS = QueryDict(request.raw_post_data)
```

However, if you're trying to use forms with Django, you should definitely look at [django.forms](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/forms/?from=olddocs). The whole forms library will just generally make your life easier; I've never written a html form by hand using Django because this part of Django takes all the work out of it. As a quick summary, you do this:

**forms.py**:

```
class FooForm(forms.Form):
    name = fields.CharField(max_length=200)
    # other properties
```

or even this:

```
class FooForm(forms.ModelForm):

    class Meta:
         model = model_name
```

Then in your request, you can pass a form out to the template:

```
def pagewithforminit(request):
    myform = FooForm()
    return render_to_response('sometemplate.html', {'nameintemplate': myform}, 
                                    context_instance=RequestContext(request))
```

And in the view that receives it:

```
def pagepostingto(request):
    myform = FooForm(request.POST)

    if myform.is_valid(): # check the fields for you:
        # do something with results. if a model form, this:
        myform.save()
        # creates a model for you.
```

See also [model forms](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/forms/modelforms/#modelform). In short, I strongly recommend django.forms.

Answer (score 0):

You can't catch GET parameters in a URL pattern. As you can see in [`django.core.handlers.base.BaseHandler.get_response`](https://code.djangoproject.com/browser/django/trunk/django/core/handlers/base.py#L100), only the part of the URL that ends up in `request.path_info` is used to resolve an URL:

```
callback, callback_args, callback_kwargs = resolver.resolve(
         request.path_info)
```

[`request.path_info`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.3/ref/request-response/#django.http.HttpRequest.path_info) does not contain the GET parameters. For handling those, see Ninefingers answer.